# MLM Bonus Cronjob

Tags: php, pdo, cron, hook, silex

I have this MLM script that I am working on. Although the project was not originally by me, I'm modifying for a client. I set up a cron job to execute the daily bonus but cron job returns sorry back not found. however, when I'm logged in as admin, function execute_bonus run via url http://mydomain/bonus/go (only when i'm logged in as admin). i'm a beginner in oop and i've been trying to debug this for days now. the internet haven't helped either. project is written with silex mframework with hooks and PDOs.

More information: Script is running on a CloudLinus 6.x OS. Error details is 404 error, but that's if I'm not logged in as the admin. I'm including cron job email notification. Click on https://trade.xperttradeoptions.com/bonus/go to see error and try logging in on https://trade.xperttradeoptions.com with cyber and 123456 and try the https://trade.xperttradeoptions.com/bonus/go again.

Currently, I'm running the cron job manually by going to http://mydomain/bonus/go after logging in as admin. The execute_bonus function runs smoothly that way but cron job GET, CURL, et al don't.
below is the code;

```
<?php
global $hooks;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
$hooks->add_action('silex_action','execute_bonus');
function execute_bonus() {
    global $app;
    $app->get('/bonus/go', function() { 
    global $hooks;
    $tgL = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-1 day'));
    if(!isWeekend($tgL)&&!isHariLibur($tgL)&&!sudahEksekusi()){ 
    $hooks->do_action('hitung_bonus');
    recordEksekusi();
    echo "DONE!";
    }else{
    echo "BEGIN TODAY PREVIOUS BONUS TODAY!";  
    }
    return "";
    }); 
}
function sudahEksekusi(){
    global $db;
    $db->bind('date',date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-1 day')));
    $log = $db->query("SELECT * FROM bonus_date_logs WHERE date = :date;");
    return (count($log)>0?true:false);
}
function recordEksekusi(){
    global $db;
    $db->query('INSERT INTO bonus_date_logs(date) VALUES (:date);',array("date"=>date("Y-m-d",strtotime('-1 day'))));
}

// Bonus Pairing
include 'bonus.pairing.php';

// Bonus Devident
include 'bonus.devident.php';
```

---

cron daemon

```
<input type='hidden' id='token' name='token' value='MTUxNTczMzI0MzpBQUFBQUFBUEFBQUxBQTBBSUFUQThIQUFBS0JsQUFCWUJnQUFBQVRnQ3dBTElRNEFBT3Z3REFDdzRQQUVzQUJRQlBFQUFEREE0UEFBS2dBUUFBb05BQT09OlkvcUVYU0Fvd3RQalE2ZTZ1OGlwSU9ZY0ZUYnl6blcwRzVTMkE0MWdLZ1pEeVZVSGVjamFFQTJUV3psY09zcHBpNGUzRkM1aHpvdEU4M3pkbXhUQ0N3PT0='
```

**message truncated**

```
trace + .trace { margin-top: 30px; }
        .trace-head .trace-class { color: #222; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; position: relative; }

        .trace-message { font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; margin: .5em 0 0; }

        .trace-file-path, .trace-file-path a { color: #222; margin-top: 3px; font-size: 13px; }
        .trace-class { color: #B0413E; }
        .trace-type { padding: 0 2px; }
        .trace-method { color: #B0413E; font-weight: bold; }
        .trace-arguments { color: #777; font-weight: normal; padding-left: 2px; }

        @media (min-width: 575px) {
            .hidden-xs-down { display: initial; }
        }</style>
</head>
<body>
                <div class="exception-summary">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="exception-message-wrapper">
                    <h1 class="break-long-words exception-message">Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.</h1>
                    <div class="exception-illustration hidden-xs-down"><svg viewBox="0 0 136 81" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="1.414"><path d="M92.358 20.403a23.168 23.168 0 0 1 9.003 1.881 23.67 23.67 0 0 1 5.197 3.079 24.257 24.257 0 0 1 3.457 3.296 24.771 24.771 0 0 1 5.042 9.396c.486 1.72.78 3.492.895 5.28l.008.142.028.158.015.246v13.875c.116.034.232.065.348.098.
```

**message truncated**

Comment: You should show the exact error details you get. Since you mention cron and "admin" you should also share the OS details since this is probably environmental.

Comment: If the cron job returns "sorry back not found" as you stated where is that coming from? There is nothing in the code you posted that would cause that phrase to be shown.